# Can an Android application include a widget or is the widget an application itself and needs to be separated from the application?

Tags: android, widget

Can an Android application include a widget or is the widget an application itself and needs to be separated from the application ?

Answer (score 0):

A home screen app widget can definitely be included in your application.  You can define as many appwidget-providers as you want along with your application.